# Oculus Keeps Saying I Don't Meet Minumum Requirements

Tags: technical-issues, oculus-rift

I have had my Oculus Rift S for a while now, but today it started saying in the main menu that my computer does not meet the minimum requirements. I have a Radeon RX 580 graphics card and an AMD Ryzen 5 2400G CPU, which is above the minimum requirements. Is there any way to get rid of the message? I talked to technical support and they said:

> I understand that your AMD Radeon RX 580 is included in our supported in our current supported graphics cards.
>
> However; the Ryzen 5 2400 is not supported by our software. This can cause compatibility issues and may limit functionality.
>
> To resolve this you would need to swap the Ryzen 5 2400 with a supported graphics card.

Comment: Their support folks are usually pretty responsive. Have you tried contacting them? It could be related to a recent update.

Comment: @roddy Ok, thanks I will talk to them.

Comment: Latest drivers installed ?

Comment: Swap the CPU with a supported graphics card, huh? Brilliant support there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Windows, you can get rid of the message using a Registry tweak:

> 1. Open *regedit* and go to "*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0*".
> 2. Change the value `ProcessorNameString` to e.g. `Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz`.
>
> <sup>[source](https://forums.oculusvr.com/community/discussion/32464/disable-your-computer-doesnt-meet-rifts-recommended-specifications-message-in-oculus-home)</sup>

You'll have to restart any Oculus Rift executables (like *OVRserver_x64.exe*).

---

In case you don't want to mess around with the Registry, here's an alternative solution, involving the renaming of files:

> Go to *C:\Users\Your username\AppData\Local\Oculus* directory (*Appdata* might be hidden - you will need to select 'View Hidden Items' in folder view). Rename the *Compatibility.json* file to *CompatibilityNew.json.temp* (file extensions might also be hidden, check 'File Name Extensions' in folder view).
>   Then change that file's security settings (<kbd>Right-click</kbd> → Properties → Security tab), so that all users/groups have "Deny" access to the file.
>
> Then go to the *C:\Program Files\Oculus\Support\oculus-runtime* directory and change the *Compatibility.json* filename to *CompatibilityNew.json*, and then change that file's security settings (<kbd>Right-click</kbd> → Properties → Security tab), so that all users/groups have "Deny" access to the file.
>
> You will then need to restart the Oculus VR Runtime Services service in the Service Manager app (Run → '*services.msc*), or reboot your system for the changes to take effect in the Oculus interface.
>
> If you are unsure of messing in these folders, make a backup of them first!
>
> <sup>[source](https://www.reddit.com/r/oculus/comments/7zd7l1/is_there_a_way_to_get_rid_of_the_your_computer/), slightly redacted</sup>

I can't test these solutions myself, unfortunately, so I'm not sure about their efficacy in your situation.